# Confirm leave page unless they clicked the save button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have a form where I create a model and I want a dialoge box to appear if the user navigates away from the page, unless they click the save/create button.

I have this javascript code that works anytime the user leaves the page; meaning this dialoge still appears when the user clicks save/create.

```
#javascripts/workouts.js.coffee
window.confirmExit = () ->
  "Your changes will not be saved.";

#workouts/new.html.haml
= render 'form'
:javascript
  window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit

#workouts_form.html.haml
= simple_form_for(@workout) do |f|
# some input fields
= f.button :submit
```

Now I know that I only want the confirm exit called if the `submit` button is not clicked, but I am not sure how to go about doing this.

Comment: Note that `window.confirmExit` will not actually do anything; you need to use `confirm "Your changes will not be saved."` or something similar.

Comment: @Len `window.confirmExit` works in chrome and safari; which browser are you using?

Comment: my bad, I didn't research this properly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out, at least it works for chrome and safari although right now I am under the impression that it will not work for ie. What I did was create a boolean that is set to false and only set to true when the submit button is selected.

```
#javascripts/workouts.js.coffee
window.submitButtonClicked = false
window.confirmExit = () ->
  if window.submitButtonClicked
    null
  else
    "Your changes will not be saved."

$(document).ready ->
  $('#target').submit ->
    window.submitButtonClicked = true

#workouts/new.html.haml
:javascript
  window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit

#workouts_form.html.haml
#target
  = simple_form_for(@workout) do |f|
    # some input fields
    = f.button :submit
```

I hope this helps anyone who was curious. Note that the `#target` line is actual haml and not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is I only show the confirmation when changes actually have been made to the form. To do that, you'll need to scan the forms on your page, serialize them and store it in memory. Then, when the user leaves the page, serialize the form again and see if there is a difference.

Otherwise, you might want to bind some function to submit event of the form, setting some global boolean like `window.formSubmitted` to true. Check that variable when leaving the page to determine if you want to show the confirmation box.